# Почему этот код работает если ничего не возврашает

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Да, для многих из вас это может показаться тупым вопросом, но да, я его не понимаю.
Пытаюсь выучить алгоритмы, и на freecodecamp увидел такой интересный код, но не могу понять как он работает. То есть, я понимаю этот алгоритм, обычная сортировка, но почему она возврашает что-то я понять не могу.

js

```
 function swap(a,b,array){
    let tmp = array[a]
    array[a] = array[b]
    array[b] = tmp
 }

 function selectionSort2(array) {
   for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
     let min = i;
     for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
       if (array[min] > array[j]) min = j;
     }
     swap(i,min,array) // почему оно что-то возврашает? 0_0 ведь в той функции нет return
   }
   return array;
 }
 
 console.log(selectionSort2([1, 4, 2, 8, 345, 123, 43, 32, 5643, 63, 123, 43, 2, 55, 1, 234, 92]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Оно ничего не возвращает. Оно меняет местами значения двух элементов массива, ссылка на который передается в третьем параметре.

Comment: я понимаю как работает сортировка, но почему функция что-то возврашает, вот в чем был вопрос, ведь внутри swap - нету return

Comment: @Cthulhu А я Вам ответил, что функция ничего не возвращает, a меняет местами значения двух элементов массива, ссылка на который передается в третьем параметре.

Comment: @Cthulhu Почему Вы решили, что функция что-то возврашает? И что Вы под этими словами понимаете?

Comment: зачем спрашивать несколько раз один и тот же вопрос, когда есть коментарий в коде?А так же изменять свой коментарий?

Comment: как я понял, при передачи параметра в функцию происходит лишь ссылка? (лол, ну да, это в общем то логично)